# Group and count records in a SQL Server table with first occurrence by group (PARTITION BY)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following columns:

```
ID - int
Time - DateTime
Message - nvarchar(max)
```

I'd like to select distinct messages, number of occurences of each message and the first time of each message. I'd also like to avoid nesting SQLs.

This is an example of the SQL I'm trying to construct:

```
SELECT [Message], FIRST_VALUE([Time]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Message] order by [Time]), COUNT(*) 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [Time]
ORDER BY [Time]
```

It doesn't work, but I believe it's a good starting point. How should I change this SQL to make it work?

Comment: Some data would be nice ?

Comment: Your query never works due, for example, you use "message" field in the select but it does not participate in the group part.

Comment: If you want distinct message, then you need to group by message, not time... (which you do for the partition, but bizarrely not for the main query).  Then, the first time value is just `min(time)`

Comment: Hello @Marko, does any of the answers help you ? Do you know what to do(what you can do) when someone answers your questions and helps you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I'd like to select distinct messages = `GROUP BY  [Message]`
- Number
  of occurences of each message = `count([Message])`
- the first time of
  each message = `min([TIME])`

  ```
  SELECT [Message] , min([TIME]), count([Message])
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY  [Message]
  ```

Here is a small demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8727597f20fd6c39867c5f2b5c3316c1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `message` field to the `group by` statement and you don't need to use window function. only use `min()` aggregate function.

```
SELECT [Message], MIN([Time]) as First_Time, COUNT(*) 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [Message]
```